# The defining relations for a subgroup of $SL(2,Z)$

Tags: gr.group-theory

$SL(2,Z)$ generated by $T=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 0& 1\\ \end{pmatrix}$ and $S=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ -1& 0\\ \end{pmatrix}$ has the following defining relations
$S^2=(S T)^3=C,\ C^2=1$. I wonder, if the subgroup $\Lambda\subset SL(2,Z)$ generated by $T^2$ and $S$ has a similar defining relations?

Comment: I think defining relations for the subgroup generated by $s=S$ and $b=T^2$ will be $s^2=c$, $[b,c]=c^2=1$.

Comment: It appears that [b,c]=0, since $S^2=-1$.

Comment: In my presentation $\langle s,b,c\mid s^2=c,[b,c]=c^2=1\rangle$, $[b,c]$ is not redundant, so what do you mean?

Comment: What is the definition of $[b,c]$? If it is defined as $bc-cb$, then the operation $-$ is not defined for a group. Also, for the 2-dim representation in the question, $s^2=c=-1$, which implies $bc-cb=0$.

Comment: In groups, $[b,c]$ usually denotes $b^{-1}c^{-1}bc.$

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Unfortunately, $[b,c]$ seems to denote $bcb^{-1}c^{-1}$ roughly half the time! Of course it makes no difference here. I can confirm that YCor's presentation is correct, using a computer calculation.

Comment: @DerekHolt :Yes, I was going to mention the alternative, depending on right-left preferences, but I suppose I was lazy.